# RadGrid + ASP.NET + IE10 Issue

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I've added a RadGrid to an older ASPX and it works fine in Chrome and FireFox.  Internet Explorer 10 does not render any of the sprites like the green plus sign for 'Insert new record' or even the funnels for the filter buttons.  Clicking the empty space where the image ought to be works:  the filter menu appears as does the insert form template appears.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the cause of this?

Some notes:

- I have changed the meta tag to IE-9 compatibility with no success.
  The console in IE shows an error when calling __defineGetter__.  I haven't traced this too far; not sure if it's relevant to my problem.
- The RadGrid operates fine, the only issue is that IE10 does not load 
  the image sprites. I've cleared my cache multiple times and have had 
  another user test it with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RadGrid should work out of the box with IE 10.  Make sure you're running the latest version of the Telerik controls and clean out IE 10's cache.  If that doesn't work I would check with Telerik's support directly...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the DocType, try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Make sure compatibility mode is not being used:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```